# Organization Concept Design

Tags: site-collection, architecture, design, infrastructure

Say I have an organization structured like so...

-- Root Host

---- Group A

------ Project of A as P1

--------- Sub Project of P1 as SP1

----------- Sub Project of SP1 as SSP1

----------- Sub Project of SP1 as SSP2

--------- Sub Project of P1 as SP2

----- Group B

------ Project of B as P2

--------- Sub Project of P2 as SP1

--------- Sub Project of P2 as SP2

N-Levels possible but will probably stop around the 5th or 6th level.

How would you set up the user groups and site structure if its possible to have admins at every level?